# Losing decimal places when exporting to csv

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper, number-formatting, export-to-csv

I am exporting data from oracle table into a csv file. I have a column of varchar2 datatype and it has values like 1.1 and 1.10. When I export these to a csv file the value 1.10 becomes 1.1 and thus creating duplicate records. Is there a way to get both the values 1.10, 1.1  into csv file without loosing the last zero in "1.10".

Thanks

Comment: The number 1.1 is exactly identical to the number 1.10 (or 1.100 or 1.1000).  You can call `to_char` to produce strings with different numbers of trailing 0's but you'd need to know how many decimal places you wanted.  If you're really using a `float` and that column is unique, one of them must not be exactly the value you think it is.

Comment: OK.  Then how are you exporting the data to CSV and how are you reading the CSV data?  Is it possible that whatever application (i.e. Excel) is writing or reading the data thinks the column is a number rather than a string?

Comment: I am using sqldeveloper and pl/sql developer and using excel to open the csv file. Ideally it should display the number as it is since its a varchar. But this is not happening. When I export it in xls format I am getting the correct result. But not with csv. Bu I want the file to be in csv format.

Comment: If you open the CSV file in a text editor, is the 0 there?  By default, Excel will generally treat a column in a CSV file that contains numeric data as a number rather than as text if you open it.  You'd need to specify that the column should be treated as text data when you open the CSV file in the wizard Excel gives you.

Comment: I am able to see the correct values when I open in notepad++.

Comment: OK.  Then it's an Excel display issue.  When you're opening the file, you need to specify that this column is text in the wizard Excel walks you through when opening text files.

Comment: I tried specifying the column as text using "text to columns" option in "date" tab, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

> When I export these to a csv file the value 1.10 becomes 1.1 and thus creating duplicate records.

This has nothing to do with **Oracle**. It is a **display** problem with the **tool** you are using. use proper formatting of cells to display up to required **decimal places**.

Also, `1.1` and `1.10` are same. Appending **zeroes** to the right after decimal makes no significant difference to the value.

**Excel Text Formatting**

1. **Right click** on the cell.
2. Select **Format Cells**.
3. In the first tab Number, select **Text**.
4. Click **OK**.

Text format cells are treated as text even when a number is in the cell. 
The cell is displayed exactly as entered.

[image]

Comment: Numerically they are same. But the column I am using is not a number its of type varchar2. So I want the trailing zero's as well.

Comment: I already tried this but it did not work. When I export from sqldev I am not able to see the values that have trailing zeros. As you said changing it to text also did not work. But its working fine when exported to excel.

Comment: Yes I saw it.You entered 1.1 and 1.10 and changed the type to text.I did the same but it did not work. when I export from oracle to csv format I am not seeing 1.10 .1.1 all I am seeing is 1.1 twice.

Comment: @sandywho Did you export as string using to_char?

Comment: As it is a varchar2 I dont think its necessary. But I even tried that but no use. The select statement I use shows both 1.10 & 1.1 The problem is with the "export to csv".